# Mesh changes its position when adding armature modifier

Tags: armature

I have a rigged body and I want to put some clothes on it. I fit it to the body mesh, then transfer weights from the body to the clothing item. But when I add the armature modifier to it and choose the body skeleton, the mesh changes its position and slightly deforms. Could you please help me with the direction where I should look?

[image]

[image: I]

Comment: is your armature in Rest Position mode?

Comment: No, I don't think so. When I try to apply it as rest pose, the body oddly deforms.

Comment: maybe share your file so that we can see, maybe the simplest way is to use weight paint